# Using a Flow Inside A Process Builder Process to Prevent Dupes

Tags: visual-workflow

I recently created a Process Builder process that identifies records coming in from one of our FormAssembly forms and steers them to the correct campaign to which they should be added. But, I am faced with the issue of duplication happening in the campaign. I know there is a way to prevent this with an auto-launched Flow but I am having trouble creating it. Has anyone done this before and if so how? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of duplicates are being created?

My preference with FormAssembly is to do the duplicate lookup checking within FormAssembly connector.

Do you have some more data on what is coming in and what on that data determines the campaign it should be linked to?